# Retrieving a paragraph from a word document using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

The following code will allow me to insert a paragraph from a word document using VBA (keeping the original formats)

```
Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
WordApp.Visible = True
Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open(aFile)

WordDoc.Paragraphs(2).Range.Copy
Selection.Paste

WordDoc.Close
WordApp.Quit
```

However is there any quicker way (that doesn't involve opening an instance of word, and then closing it)

Comment: Look at Office Open XML. It's possible to access a Word document direclty from the closed file, by "unzipping" it and manipulating the XML in the "document parts" that make up the file. VBA doesn't do this natively, however, it requires outside libraries that can work with Zip packages and for the XML. The MSXML parser is part of Windows and can handle the latter, but the Zip packaging part is more difficult. VB.NET and C# are the better choices in this respect...

Comment: Can the people who down-voted my question please explain why it has been down-voted

Comment: Possibly because it's unclear: You don't say where your code is running and to what kind of target you're pasting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works perfectly, although it does involve an additional stage.

The following code will insert a Word document into the current document

```
Selection.InsertFile "C:\myFile.docx"
```

If I want a specific paragraph, then I can prepare the word document by adding bookmarks to each paragraph. (This is relatively trivial to do using VBA)

```
Sub StripAllBookmarks()
    Dim stBookmark As Bookmark
    ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.ShowHidden = True
    If ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Count >= 1 Then
       For Each stBookmark In ActiveDocument.Bookmarks
          stBookmark.Delete
       Next stBookmark
    End If
End Sub
Sub addBookmarks()
  StripAllBookmarks
  c = 1
  For Each para In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
    ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Add Name:="B" + Trim(c), Range:=para.Range
    c = c + 1
  Next para
End Sub
```

Let us say the first paragraph has bookmark set to "B1" and the second paragraph has bookmark set to "B2". The following code will add the first paragraph instantaneously

```
Selection.InsertFile "C:\myFile.docx", Range:="b1"
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the reason you don't want to open the file (maybe someone is using), but you can make a clone of that file and use the clone file. This way you don't open the original file :P

Comment: As highlighted in the question, the reason why I don't want to open the file in the manner in which I described, is for speed reasons.